# Why is it "Not possible to simply pass a NULL value using native dynamic SQL"?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am confused as to the meaning of something I just read in the book [Oracle PL/SQL Recipes](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430232072).

In recipe 8-12, it states:

> It is not possible to simply pass a `NULL` value using native dynamic
>   SQL.  At least, you cannot pass a `NULL` as a literal.

What that suggests to me is that something like the following **(A)**:

```
DECLARE
  v_string varchar2(255);
  v_count natural;
BEGIN
  v_string := 'SELECT count(*) INTO :count FROM item WHERE color IS NOT NULL';


  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_string INTO v_count;

  dbms_output.put_line('Count: ' || v_count);
END;
```

Would not work properly.  It suggests **(B)**:

> Passing an uninitialized variable via the EXECUTE IMMEDIATE statement
>   will have the same effect as substituting a `NULL` value for a bind
>   variable.

The book's example code:

```
DECLARE
  TYPE cur_type IS REF CURSOR;
  cur                cur_type;
  null_value    CHAR(1);
  sql_string     VARCHAR2(150);
  emp_rec       employees%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  sql_string := 'SELECT * ' ||
                          'FROM EMPLOYEES ' ||
                       'WHERE MANAGER_ID IS :null_val';

  OPEN cur FOR sql_string USING null_value;
  LOOP
    FETCH cur INTO emp_rec;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(emp_rec.first_name || ' ' || emp_rec.last_name || 
                                                        ' - ' || emp_rec.email);
    EXIT WHEN cur%NOTFOUND;
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE cur;
 END;
/
```

So my confusion is this: method **(A)** seems to behave just fine for me, whether I run the query dynamically or not, it is properly selecting records without `NULL` (or with them, if I invert the conditional).

So what's the deal with this?  I'm running Oracle 11g release 2.

Comment: In A you're not passing anything though... it doesn't fulfil the conditions stated.

Comment: @Ben - Can you explain?

Comment: @Tom, what Ben means is that (A) doesn't have any variables going IN to the statement - it only has one OUT bind variable - it doesn't matter whether `v_count` is initialised or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're not allowed to write is :

```
OPEN cur FOR sql_string USING NULL;
```

when you could write :

```
OPEN cur FOR sql_string USING 'A string';
```

There's nothing more to it.